# Añadir leyenda lateral derecha en a un plot en R

Tags: r

Tengo un conjunto de datos con cuatro niveles para mi variable x: x1, x1, x3, x4.

He realizado un gráfico utilizando el siguiente código:

```
means <- tapply(y,x1,mean)
plot(means, col="red",pch=18,type = 'l')
```

Después he añadido para x2, x3 y x4, el resto de medias.

```
lines(means, col="blue",pch=18)
```

El gráfico obtenido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría añadir una pequeña leyenda en el lateral derecho que representara el color de cada valor de x.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Pyring te pongo la instrucción que necesitas y un poco de código para un ejemplo muy sencillito.

Usaremos la función legend:

```
legend(x, y=NULL, legend, fill, cex, bg)
```

- x, y: són para situar la leyenda, teniendo en cuenta que la leyenda es cuadrada y se empezará a dibujar desde el lado izquierdo superior.
- legend: los niveles que crees que aparezcan escritos en la leyenda.
- fill: los colores que quieres que aparezcan en el cuadro.
- cex: es para modificar el tamaño para el texto.
- bg: color de fondo de la leyenda

Y aquí te dejo el código:

```
set.seed(123)
x=runif(30,-300,300)
y=runif(30,-300,300)
plot(x,y,ylab="Variable 1",xlab="Variable2",
ylim=c(-500,500),xlim=c(-500,500),col=c("red","blue"))
legend(x=380,y=495,legend=c("Nivel1","Nivel2"),
fill=c("red","blue"),cex=0.4,text.font=4, bg='grey')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]